# How to position a custom top level menu before/after some menu?

Tags: hooks, menu

While [this documentation](https://wiki.civicrm.org/confluence/display/CRMDOC/hook_civicrm_navigationMenu) tells how to add a custom top level menu, it adds to the last. Say, I want to add a new custom menu "My Menu" and position it right before "Administer" menu. How would I do this?

Answer (score 1):

Pretty sure you need to GET `weight` of the "Administer" menu and then based on that you can SET the `weight` for "My Menu" - in the civicrm_navigation table. like in Drupal I think you'll be ok having two items with the same weight - no need to renumbering them all!